# How to display the right content for the right URL?

Tags: php, url, subdomain

I have two domain names for my website. Everything is the same in the two of them except the banner and the footer

the first is `wwww.example.com.au`

the second is `wwww.example.co.th`

How to use PHP get domain name to display the right content for the right domain ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code in a common config place,

```
$domainName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$countryCode = array_pop(explode('.', $domainName));
if($countryCode == 'au') {
    $banner = "";
    $footer = "";
} else if($countryCode == 'th') {
    $banner = "";
    $footer = "";
}
```

Comment: I hope my answer helps you. Can i have your contact for some technical discussion in future too? skypeID please?

Answer (score 1):

use `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` to get your domain then set your condition according to your requirement.